# DB2 declared temporary table varchar returns error -443

Tags: sql, database, string, db2, dbvisualizer

I'm trying to query a DB2 and I declare a temporary table like this

```
declare global temporary table session.results
    (code_statement varchar, count_statement integer) with replace on commit preserve rows not logged;

delete from session.results;
```

I then insert into the table with multiple statements like this one

```
insert into session.results(code_statement, count_statement)
    values ('tA full join tB',
        (select count(*) as count_statement from tableA A full join tableB B on A.key = B.key));
```

The problem is that when I do any of this insertions (no matter if I use `full join` or any other) and use something >= 21 characters for the `varchar` value, SQL returns `[Error Code: -433, SQL State: 22001]  DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-433, SQLSTATE=22001, SQLERRMC=<text>, DRIVER=3.50.152`

I've tested and I'm 100% sure this is the problem. Whenever I insert 21+ characters in that string, it crashes.

I've tried to use `varchar(50)`, `varchar(400)`, `char(50)` and it does not get solved.

I've also checked docs and googled for hours and haven't found any solution.

Thanks in advance.

---

***UPDATE***:  I have no idea how but it is now working as expected. It requires to set a size to the varchar, and also accepts bigger strings. The point is that I have no idea what happened and why it's solved. I just kept playing around and split the `declare` into multiple lines. Also changed "`Max Chars`" in DbVis (from -1 to 100) but I have set it back and it's still working.

It makes no sense for me. I'll keep the question opened since I don't know what solved the issue.

Comment: Db2 should throw an exception (sqlcode -604) for the declare dgtt, if you don't size the varchar column. At least, that's what Db2 V11.1 on unix does when using the CLP.

Comment: @mao I have updated the question. Indeed it now throws **`-604`** when not setting `varchar`'s size. Any kind of cache, buffering... hidden magic?

Answer (score 0):

Db2 requires that you specify an integer value to size the varchar.
Otherwise Db2 should throw an sqlcode -604 exception.
You need to size the column appropriately, taking into account character encoding if using utf-8.
If you have a reproducible, portable, scenario that shows the -433 (value too long) exception when using valid syntax and values then update the question.

Comment: As already pointed out, the problem was not only that syntax was incorrect. That's simply because now it complains when I do not set `varchar`'s size, but it was not before. Before, it was not complaining and the error it was complaining about was AFTER the `declare` statement. Besides that, when I commented out the line which was forcing the **`-433`**, the script was running correctly.

Comment: Always useful to compare client-tool (dbvis) behaviour to CLP when unexpected results happen.